# label and :checked selector not working in flask

Tags: css, flask, checkbox

I'm working on a website menu with html in **flask** and **css**.

Issues:

1. I expect that when I click on the label (`label for="toggle"`) the checkbox is checked, however this is not working.
2. I expect that when the checkbox is checked the below code is triggered, however this is not working.

Ad2)

```
.toggle:checked + .wrapper > aside {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.toggle:checked + .wrapper > section {
    margin-right: -40%;
}
```

**html file:**

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Application Name</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Application Name">
    <link rel="favorite icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base-theme.css') }}" id="mode_stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/switch_mode.js') }}"></script>
</head>    
<body>    
    <div class="topnav">
        <table class="topnav_left">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="toggle" class="toggler">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="offcanvas" class="toggle">
                            <span class="navicon"></span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="topnav_right">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="topnav_mode">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="mode_toggle" class="mode_switch">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="mode_toggle">
                                                <span class="mode_slider"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <aside>
            <nav>
                <a href="/">HOME</a>
                <a href="/api">API</a>
                <br />
                <p>Versions</p>
                <br />
                <a href="/api/v1/test">Test</a>
            </nav>
        </aside>
    </div>    
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% block body %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>    
</body>    
</html>
```

**css file:**

```
/* Off-canvas sidebar - start */

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.row {
    padding: -15px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

aside {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #333;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.toggle:checked + .wrapper > aside {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.toggle:checked + .wrapper > section {
    margin-right: -40%;
}

.toggler {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navicon {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: url("../img/topnav/navicon.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
}
/* Off-canvas sidebar - end */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

> To associate the `<label>` with an `<input>` element, you need to give the `<input>` an `id` attribute. The `<label>` then needs a for an attribute whose value is the same as the input's `id`.

You've used a class, instead it should be e.g.:

```
 <label for="offcanvas" class="toggler">
     <input type="checkbox" id="offcanvas" class="toggle">
     <span class="navicon"></span>
 </label>
```

The second problem is with this css selector:

```
.toggle:checked + .wrapper > aside {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.toggle:checked + .wrapper > section {
    margin-right: -40%;
}
```

The `+` selector is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), which means your `.wrapper` would need to be the sibling following your `.toggle:checked` element. Currently, it is a long way from being an adjacent sibling (and as there are no CSS rules that can reach 'up' the DOM tree there's no valid selector you can use with this current html structure).

Luckily, there is a neat trick you can do here, as long as you don't actually need the original checkbox to be visible. You can move the `input` element out of your label (the label-for keeps them bound still) and put it somewhere where a CSS rule can do what you want.

So in your case:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="offcanvas" class="toggle">
 <div class="wrapper">
        <aside>
            <nav>
                <a href="/">HOME</a>
                <a href="/api">API</a>
                <br />
                <p>Versions</p>
                <br />
                <a href="/api/v1/test">Test</a>
            </nav>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?


`<label for="toggle" class="toggler">
    <input type="checkbox" id="offcanvas" class="toggle">
    <span class="navicon"></span>
</label>`

Comment: I see my mistake now, I did not use the `id` but the `class`. The second issue still persists so I changed the description above.

Comment: what's not working - the css isn't being applied?

Comment: It should move the sidemenu `<aside>` from hidden (`margin-left: -40%;`) to visible (`margin-left: 0`).

Comment: have added an extra section for your CSS problem